# How do I figure out which Javascript code is periodically hanging the browser?

Tags: javascript

It's not freezing the page until I refresh, it's just every 10 seconds or so hanging for a few seconds while I'm typing or clicking in the page (I of course won't notice if I'm not interacting with the page, and there's no moving graphics).

I didn't build the page or the form, but it's heavy Javascript and I'm unable to edit the Javascript source code (except in Chrome Dev Tools) but I'd like to know if there's a way to catch which code keeps hanging user interactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Collect JavaScript CPU Profile` in Chrome Dev Tools, press record, click around, stop, and evaluate. Details:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

If you have access to the source code you can use the [Performance API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance)